# Dynamically create divs with incremented id using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a text
I want to append multiple divs but the id should be changed dynamically.
e.g:

```
<div id=first>text</div>
<div id=first0>text</div>
<div id=first1>text</div>
<div id=first2>text</div>
<div id=first3>text</div>
<div id=first4>text</div>
<div id=first5>text</div>
```

Any help? thanks..

Comment: What exactly have you tried? You can just use `.attr('id', 'myID');`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347798/jquery-changing-an-element-id

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your title and question content seem to disagree with each other. I am assuming you are wanting to create div's where each id sequentially increments each time one is created?

```js
$(function(){
  var count = 0;
  $('#append').click(function(){
    $('#parent').append('<div id="first'+count+'">text</div>');
    count++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="append">Add DIV</a>
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Mine is a little more complex but this will be a good start

Comment: this made my day!

Answer (score 11):

You can change it with [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('#first').attr('id', 'first6')
```

Answer (score 2):

try to change the code to :

```
<div id="first">text</div>
<div id="first0">text</div>
<div id="first1">text</div>
<div id="first2">text</div>
<div id="first3">text</div>
<div id="first4">text</div>
<div id="first5">text</div>
```

dont forget the `id` inside " " (`id="first"` not `id=first`)

now you can simply use jquery : `$("#first").attr('id','first6');`

Answer (score 1):

If you were interested in how styling works.`

```js
$(function(){
  for (let i = 0 ;i < 10; i ++){  
      $('#foo').append('<div id="first'+i+'">text</div>');
  }
});
```

```css
#first4 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a div with id=Container and the create 5 divs dynamically using following code

```
//using JavaScript
 for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
     var obj = document.getElementById("container");
     obj.innerHTML += '<div id="first'+i+'"></div>';
 }
```