# How to assign dynamic id in HTML5+Thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

HTML

```
<form id="searchPersonForm" action="#" th:object="${person}" method="post">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="person_id" th:field="*{person_id}"></input>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="child_id" th:field="*{child_id}"></input>
</form>
```

How to assign dynamic id like person_id_100,person_id_200... and child_id_100, child_id_200... The values 100, 200 are actual person_ids.

Can we do without jQuery ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically create divs with incremented id using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926484/dynamically-create-divs-with-incremented-id-using-jquery)

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadkari Thanks. But is it possible to do without jQuery. Like id="person + 'person_id'".

Comment: Take a look at [thymeleaf forum]( http://forum.thymeleaf.org/How-to-get-id-values-dynamicaly-td4026516.html), there is a solution using th:each and a counter to set id for input elements.

Comment: @GuillermoFernández. Thanks. I will try the solution.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is probably worth learning if you plan on getting serious, but this can be done with a simple javascript file:

```
//saved as javascript.js

var formId = "searchPersonForm";
var inputArray = [];
for(var x=0;x < 10;x++){
    var newId = x*100
    var newInput = document.createElement("input")
    newInput.id = "person_id_" + newId
    inputArray.push(newInput);
}
for(var x=0;x < inputArray.length;x++){
    document.getElementById(formId).appendChild(inputArray[x])
    console.log(inputArray[x].id)
}
```

And just include the script in your page at some point after the form is instantiated:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="searchPersonForm" action="#" th:object="${person}" method="post">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="person_id" th:field="*{person_id}"></input>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="child_id" th:field="*{child_id}"></input>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
</form>
</body>
```

Output:

```
person_id_0
javascript.js:11 person_id_100
javascript.js:11 person_id_200
javascript.js:11 person_id_300
javascript.js:11 person_id_400
javascript.js:11 person_id_500
javascript.js:11 person_id_600
javascript.js:11 person_id_700
javascript.js:11 person_id_800
javascript.js:11 person_id_900
```

Comment: Np.  Btw, not sure if you know but if you find an answer or a comment helpful you can thumb it up.