# How to show and hide div using Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a button and a div in a ngfor loop
and I want each button to be able to show and hide the div each time i click on it
the problem is that I don't already know the number of buttons and div it depends on the data in my database. just want every button to be responsible on the div next  to it:

here is the code:

```html
<div *ngFor="let par1 of lstUser1">

  <button id="bt2" class="arrow2" (click)="arrowButton('bt2')">
    my button
  </button>

  <div>
    my div to show and hide
  </div>

</div>
```

and here is an example of the design i'm trying to make

[image]

Comment: What about using angular material tree ?https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuo can use for show and hide div

> *ngIf

```
 <div *ngFor="let par1 of lstUser1">
         
          <button id="bt2" class="arrow2"
          (click)="changeMyDivStatus()">
          my button
          </button>
          
          <div *ngIf="showMyDiv">
              my div to show and hide
         </div>
 </div>
```

**.ts file must have "showMyDiv" variable** as boolean variable

```
changeMyDivStatus(){
   showMyDiv = !showMyDiv;
}
```

Comment: but if i do that it wouldnt get which div i want to show especially because i have 3 nested loops each one have an endefinde number of buttons and divs so i cant make only one variable for all of them .

Comment: I just say how to use *ngIf. You must specify id and you can use it for  nested loops to sepicified ids.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7927456/5736794 can help you. I think you must write nested for loops in .ts file.