# Interchange Div id's simultaneously using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have two div's

```
    <div id="one">xyz</div>
    <div id="two">abc</div>
    <input id="reverse" type="button" value="Reverse" />
```

On click of the button, the the id's of the div needs to get interchanged.

```
    $('#one').attr('id', 'two');
    $('#two').attr('id', 'one');
```

would obviously be false, can anyone help me regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache the selector first so it holds a reference to the element, then swap the `id` attributes.

```
var one = $('#one');
$('#two').attr('id', 'one');
one.attr('id', 'two');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/caByJ/).

Comment: Thanks for the letting me know on how to cache the selectors. It worked  nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
$('#reverse').click(function() {
    var $one = $('#one');
    var $two = $('#two');
    $one.attr('id', 'two');
    $two.attr('id', 'one');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9zNq6/

If you're really paranoid then:

```
$('#reverse').click(function() {
    var $one = $('#one');
    var $two = $('#two');
    $one.removeAttr('id');
    $two.attr('id', 'one');
    $one.attr('id', 'two');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/uQnpY/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be messing around with IDs in that fashion; if it is a matter of positioning, using a class variable makes more sense. Are you sure you can't use addclass/removeclass for your purposes?

Out of curiousity, would switching the content of the two be sufficient?

If you wanted to switch the content, it would be pretty simple:

```
    function switch_contents(){
            var one_contents = $('#one').html();
            $('#one').html($('two').html());
            $('#two').html(one_contents);
    }
```

If you are really interested in actually switching the IDs, there is an example with switching IDs over here; [Changing an element's ID with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347798/jquery-changing-an-element-id)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am new to jQuery, you have provided me an alternative to the solution.

Comment: Switching the `innerHTML` is rarely ideal.