# Changing div in iframe using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a "Page A". In this page is an `iframe` which displays "Page B".

```
<iframe id="iframeD" src="https://trello.com" width="600" height="600">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
<div id="cTitle">Hello</div>​
```

(See the following fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/noscirre/yYkUN/)

"Page B" contains a `div` with id `landingHeader`. How can I create a jQuery call on "Page A" replace this `div` with another `div` (whose content is found on "Page A") with id `cTitle`?

Comment: IF it is possible it will be something like `$("iframe #dTitle").before($("#cTitle")).remove();`

Comment: If you want to access contents of an iframe from it's parent you must avoid incurring same origin policy restrictions; make sure `src` is  to the same domain, a relative location or some undefined javascript (e.g. `javascript:undefined;`).

Answer (score 5):

```
 $("iframe").contents().find("#dTitle").attr('id','cTitle').html($('#cTitle').html());
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're not violating the **same origin policy**,

1, Give your iframe an *id* - `<iframe id="frm" src="javascript:undefined;"></iframe>​`
2, Get the `Window` and `HTMLDocument` from the frame

```
var iWin = document.getElementById('frm').contentWindow,  
    iDoc = iWin.document;
```

3, Ceck for existance of jQuery in iframe

```
if( ! iWin.$ ){
    var jq = iDoc.createElement('script');
    jq.type = 'text/javascript';
    jq.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js';
    jq.onload = ready;
    iDoc.head.appendChild(jq);
}else{
    ready(); // the stuff you want to do
}
```

4, Do what you want with jQuery

```
function ready(){
    var div = iWin['$']('#frm_div')[0]; // example from fiddle
    div.textContent = 'bar';
}​
```

See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CTJW2/).

Answer (score 1):

You can change so only if the iframe domain is same as the parent domain. If it is so then you can change it by accessing the iframe from the parent window using the contentWindow property.

Answer (score 0):

Go and check this post [Changing an element's ID with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347798/changing-an-elements-id-with-jquery)

```
$(this).attr("id","newId");
```

Comment: i think he wants a full element replace

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change just content then do this:

```
$("div#bTitle").html($("div#cTitle").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $("#iFrame").contents().find("#dTitle").attr('id','cTitle');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the iFrame might be an issue unless both share the same parent DOM.  However, regardless, just for fun, i kicked up this quick and simple jQuery plguin for ya that could help.

> Plugin *updated* <sub>It makes more sense to return the replacment than the old element, thus changed</sub>

```
$(function() {
    if (!$.replaceWith) {
        $.extend({
            replaceWith: function(ele, newEle) {
                ele.each(function(i) { $(this).before(newEle).remove(); });
                return newEle;
            }
        });
        $.fn.extend({
            replaceWith: function(newEle) { return $.replaceWith($(this), newEle); }
        });
    }
});
```

> Simple USE

```
$("#someElementID").replaceWith($("#anotherElementID"));
// or
$.replaceWith($("#someElementID"), $("#anotherElementID"));
```

> For Instance:

```
$("#dTitle").replaceWith($("#cTitle"));
```

Comment: Hi SpYk3HH, I am really grateful for the your efforts to help me. I tried your solution but unfortunately despite your efforts, it doesn't seem to work for me. I've made a fiddle using trello.com as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/noscirre/yYkUN/

Comment: As i mentioned to start, your main issue there is that the iframe html is not in the same DOM as the html calling the iframe.  In other words, trelo and jsfiddle are on two different networks all together.  There is an inherent issue with trying to accress an iframe on a different dom.  Think about it, if you could do this, then what would stop someone from setting up a hacked version of a sight, with slightly different url and basically "pirate" an entire website.  That wouldn't be very nice