# jQuery Change of classes (not updating)

Tags: jquery

I'm making a slideshow which uses both classes(Positioning) and IDs(Styling), now when I move an image, Im changing its class; but when mouseenter(class) gets triggered, jQuery is still reading the old html where .pc1 was a certain image but now its another.

Is there a way around this?

I'm trying to use this:

```
$(document).find('.pccenter').mouseenter(function(){
    if (loading != true) {
        $(this).fadeTo(1000, 1);
        $(this).parent().children('.shinepc').fadeTo(2000, 0.4);
    }
});






var position ="";
var shinepos = "";
$('.pccenter').mouseover(function(){
    position = $(document).find('.pccenter').attr('id');
    shinepos = $(document).find('.shinepc').attr('id');
    console.log(shinepos);
    console.log(position);
    if (loading != true) {
        $('#' + position).fadeTo(1000, 1);
         $('#' + shinepos).fadeTo(2000, 0.4);
    }
});

$('.pccenter').mouseleave(function(){
    position = $(document).find('.pccenter').attr('id');
    shinepos = $(document).find('.shinepc').attr('id');
    if (loading != true) {
        $('#' + position).fadeTo(1000, 0.6);
        $('#' + shinepos).fadeTo(3000, 0.2);
    }
});
```

Tried using that with:

```
<div class="pcmidr" id="pcmidr"><div class="shinepcmidr" id="shinepcmidr"></div></div>
<div class="pccenter" id="pccenter"><div class="shinepc" id="shinepc"></div></div>
```

Now the class "pcmidr" changes to pccenter and pccenter changes to pcmidl.

```
$(document).find('.pccenter').mouseleave(function(){
    if (loading != true) {
        $(this).fadeTo(1000, 0.6);
        $(this).parent().children('.shinepc').fadeTo(3000, 0.2);
    }
});
```

Comment: use mouseover event instead of mouseenter

Comment: loading is not defined , Its console error ? what is the value of loading ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing an element's ID with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347798/changing-an-elements-id-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use mouseover event instead of mouseenter

mouseover fires when the pointer moves into the child element as well, while mouseenter fires only when the pointer moves into the bound element.

Comment: mouseover fires when the pointer moves into the child element as well, while mouseenter fires only when the pointer moves into the bound element.

Comment: I think for this to wo rk, I need to get $(document).find('id') and get the class name, and work from there, should work no?

Comment: Updated the post to contain some of the html

Comment: that didn't work either pratik.. grrr kind of frustrating when you go mouseover the pcmidl, the pccenter highlights.. instead.

Comment: loading is not defined , Its console error ? what is the value of loading ??

Comment: No errors, now I'm debugging through firebug.. and the console.log(); for the $(document).find to get the exact id name for the class is still retrieving the old html unchanged class names.

Comment: what I can do which is quite stupdi and old school, put a hidden tag inside the divs to get the new class name. :/ can't believe jQuery doesn't update automatically when changing a classname..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).find('.pccenter').mouseover(function(){
    if (loading != true) {
        $(this).fadeTo(1000, 1);
        $(this).parent().children('.shinepc').fadeTo(2000, 0.4);
}
});

$(document).find('.pccenter').mouseleave(function(){
    if (loading != true) {
        $(this).fadeTo(1000, 0.6);
        $(this).parent().children('.shinepc').fadeTo(3000, 0.2);
    }
});
```

Comment: with the .parent().children() the shine layer is not fading aswell.. I have to remove it to: $('.shinepc').fadeTo()

and with mouseover, the old image is shining instead of the one I'm hovering over.

Comment: I tried using:

 $('.pccenter').mouseover(function(){
  position = $(document).find('.pccenter').attr('id');
  shinepos = $(document).find('.shinepc').attr('id');
  console.log(shinepos);
  console.log(position);
     if (loading != true) {
         $('#' + position).fadeTo(1000, 1);
          $('#' + shinepos).fadeTo(2000, 0.4);
     }
 });

but still the image previously set is highlighting.. now that shouldn't be because im getting the current.. id for the class name changed :s