# Change div id by button click with Jquery attribute

Tags: jquery

Trying to use `.click` with buttons to control the id of a div...

```
<button type="button" id="1" class="this">
  first
</button>
<button type="button" id="2" class="this">
  second
</button>
 <div id="id1"></div>



<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.this').click(function() {
        $(this).attr('#id1', '#id2');
    });
});
</script>
```

Just trying to learn jquery...
need to change the div id from `id="id1"` to `id="id2"` when the second button is clicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing an element's ID with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347798/changing-an-elements-id-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it!

When using `attr()`, you do not need the hashtag symbol for the selector part and unless you literally want a hashtag in the `ID` that you're setting then you don't need it their either.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.this').eq(1).on('click', function(){
      $('#id1').attr('id', 'id2');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="1" class="this">
  first
</button>
<button type="button" id="2" class="this">
  second
</button>
 <div id="id1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the attr() function's syntax requires the name of the attribute as the first parameter, not the current value:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.this').click(function() {
        $(this).attr('id', 'id2');
    });
});
```

p.s. this is a keyword, you should try not to use it as classname, that is bound to cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

See comments in code for explanation

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.this').click(function() {
        // you need to check if you clicked on the seccond button
        if('2' === $(this).attr('id')) {  // if seccond button
            $('#id1').attr('id', 'id2');  // change the id of id1
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#id1 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#id2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="1" class="this">
  first
</button>
<button type="button" id="2" class="this">
  second
</button>
 <div id="id1"></div>
```

Now because it's not the best approach to code like that (maintanability) and you might want to turn the `id2` back to `id1` you could do something like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('[data-toggle-id]').click(function() {
        $('.toggle-me').attr(
            'id',
            $(this).attr('data-toggle-id')
        );
    });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#id1 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#id2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-toggle-id="id1">
  first
</button>
<button type="button" data-toggle-id="id2">
  second
</button>
 <div id="id1" class="toggle-me"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the attribute parameter as in below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.this').click(function() {
    $("#id1").attr('id', 'id2');
}); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"   integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button type="button" id="1" class="this">
  first
</button>
<button type="button" id="2" class="this">
  second
</button>
<div id="id1"></div>

<script>
jQuery(function() {
    $('#2').click(function() {
       $('#id1').attr('id', 'id2');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to change an attribute is next: 
`$("mySelector").attr("attrName","newValueIWant")`

I made and example for you, hope it helps:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    console.log("Before click:")
    console.log("ID div: "+$("div").attr("id"))
    
    $("button#2").click(function() {
         $("#divId1").attr('id', 'divId2');
         console.log("After click:")
         console.log("ID div: "+$("div").attr("id"))
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="1" class="this">
  first
</button>
<button type="button" id="2" class="this">
  second
</button>
 <div id="divId1"></div>
```

Comment: Even though this works, it's bad practice to make the HTML order responsible for what should happen. Especially when the element contains the `id` with the information you're after.

Comment: Yes but this will work for the example he need. He specified change the id by clicking the second button, and after that they will have same id, wich is not reccomended.

Comment: No they will not have the same id. The button is `id="2"` and the div has `id="id2"`. But either way, what I was saying is, you can get on which button he clicked in many other (BETTER) ways then with `eq()`

Comment: Thats true thanks, I didnt read well the question, I have updated my answer.