# DOM Found 'number' elements with non-unique id "#somethingId" Deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have several jsp that I invoke, of which when I load the main page I include my jsp as attributes, the question is that ...
When I load my main page, other jsp are loaded additionally.
These are loaded, but when they load I get the following error.
[Multiple ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9ES8.png)

Now, I need to know if there is any function in javascript or Jquery where I can eliminate these duplicates of id's or from html there is a repair.
Without manually I search in all my pages and I have to change the id.

Comment: Not sure how using JavaScript would solve the problem. Not like the ids will not always be there. Fix the real issue, do not do a bandaid with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:
[Changing an element's ID with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347798/changing-an-elements-id-with-jquery)

I would do it like that:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').each(function(index) {
            if(this.id) {
                this.id = this.id + index;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```