# Create a button and put different id on each button in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a loop that creates a button on the table I only show the part where I add the button. Now the thing is I want to change the **button id="edit"** to edit01, edit02, edit03 in which will be based on the **data.length** as the loops goes on.

```js
var data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
var tb = $('#tab_d')[0];
var content = "";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  content += '<tr>' + '<td>' + '<button id="edit">' + 'Edit' + '</button>' + '</td>' + '</tr>';
}
tb.innerHTML = content;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="tab_d"></table>
```

Comment: Just change `'<button id="edit">'` to `'<button id="edit' + i + '">'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347798/changing-an-elements-id-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop just add the value of `data` using the key of `i`

```
var data  = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
var tb = $('#tab_d')[0];
var content = "";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var sn = Number(data[i]) < 10 ? ('0' + data[i]) : data[i];
    content += '<tr>'+'<td>'+'<button id="edit'+sn+'">'+'Edit'+'</button>'+'</td>'+'</tr>';
}
tb.innerHTML = content;
```